# Making a BMI calculator and trying to call a function with the heights and weights of individuals

Tags: python, function

I am trying to create a BMI calculator and am trying to call a function that has the heights and weights as parameters and returns the BMI with the formula weight × 703 / height2.

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
heights = []
weights = []
for recipient in recipients:
  heights.append(int(input("What is your height " + recipient )))
  weights.append(int(input("What is your weight " + recipient )))

def BMI(weights, heights):
  bmi_total = (weights * 703) / (heights ** 2)

  print(bmi_total)
```

The rest of the instructions are as follow:

- That body mass index should then be appended to an array.
- Using a second loop it should traverse the array of body mass indices and call another function that accepts the body mass index as a parameter and returns whether the individual is underweight, normal weight or overweight.
- The number of individuals in each category should be counted and the number in each of those categories should be displayed.
- You should decide on the names of the six individuals and the thresholds used for categorization.

Did I correctly create the function for this set of instructions?

Comment: Your question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . You should make an edit and include the input and output from your own testing also. If you are getting errors or incorrect output, you should specifically show what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close: use a `for` loop with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate though each `weight, height` of the `weights` and `heights lists:

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
heights = []
weights = []
for recipient in recipients:
  heights.append(int(input("What is your height " + recipient )))
  weights.append(int(input("What is your weight " + recipient )))

def BMI(weights, heights):
  for weight, height in zip(weights, heights):
    bmi_total = (weight * 703) / (height ** 2)
    print(bmi_total)

BMI(weights, heights)
```